# Which NSAssertion should I use inside a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We cannot use NSAssertion inside blocks because that macro uses self, creating a retain cycle, as commented here:
http://www.takingnotes.co/blog/2011/09/27/making-nsassert-play-nice-with-blocks/
My question is, what kind of assertions should I use inside a block?

Comment: What's wrong with the assertion macro used in the link your provided?

Comment: Nothing, actually I started using it. But the questions is about if xcode has something for that. It is very strange to me that. Unless you know about that, you will create retain cycles.

Comment: Note that the retain cycles only exist in Debug mode, not Release, which is why you can often get away with it even if you use `NSAssert`. (Not debating that it's a good idea to avoid it; just that it often is not as significant a problem as you would assume in practice.)

Comment: Yes I know, but they are annoying.  Specially if you see strange things in debug but not in release.

Comment: @RobNapier: You often can't get away with it because the retain cycle breaks your application. For example UIViewController should go from alloc -> viewDidLoad -> ... -> dealloc and that breaks with a retain cycle, with sometimes catastrophic results.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's interesting. Generally dealloc shouldn't do anything but release memory; anything else should be in viewDidDisappear (which will fire). You definitely can wind up holding onto a lot of memory, but generally no program logic should depend on when objects are dealloc'ed. I usually avoid these retain loops out of habit, so it's very possible I've just never run into the cases where it matters beyond an excessive high-water mark. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 8):

I generally use `NSCAssert()` in these cases. It doesn't pass `self` and is also useful for assertions inside of C functions.

Comment: finally. bingo :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with retain cycles by using `self` in a block, you could `@weakify(self)` outside of the block, and inside `@strongify(self)` again, as explained very well [here](http://holko.pl/2015/05/31/weakify-strongify/).

Comment: I'm using them, but using them NSAssertions is too much

Comment: That's first a macro that isn't part of Cocoa, and second irrelevant to the question. The point is that NSAssert uses self without the programmer being aware (and often only in DEBUG builds), when the user didn't actually have the slightest intention to use self.

Comment: Well, in the question it was explicitly mentioned that the macro uses self, and my suggestion was to avoid retain cycles related to it. It is to my opinion thus not irrelevant to the question. Further, the macro is very often used, even if it not a part of Cocoa.